# Microsoft graph calling/communication SDK not working with MediaSession

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am making calls to teams user using Graph Communication SDK with local machine.I am using ngork for making local machine endpoints public. I can make call to teams user without using MediaSession but when I use Media Session call is not reaching to teams user and it is not giving any error.Need help to find out issue.I am referring examples from this doc- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples

Working Call:

```
var mediaToPrefetch = new List<MediaInfo>();
        var call = new Call()
        {
            Targets = new[] { target },
            MediaConfig = new ServiceHostedMediaConfig { PreFetchMedia = mediaToPrefetch },
            RequestedModalities = new List<Modality> { Modality.Audio, Modality.Video, Modality.VideoBasedScreenSharing },
            TenantId = joinCallBody.TenantId,
        };
        var statefulCall = await this.Client.Calls().AddAsync(call, scenarioId: scenarioId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Non Working Call:

```
var mediaSession=this.CreateMediaSession();
var mediaToPrefetch = new List<MediaInfo>();
        var call = new Call()
        {
            Targets = new[] { target },
            MediaConfig = new ServiceHostedMediaConfig { PreFetchMedia = mediaToPrefetch },
            RequestedModalities = new List<Modality> { Modality.Audio, Modality.Video, Modality.VideoBasedScreenSharing },
            TenantId = joinCallBody.TenantId,
        };
        var statefulCall = await this.Client.Calls().AddAsync(call, scenarioId: scenarioId,mediaSession:mediaSession).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those samples refer to application-hosted media bots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/requirements-considerations-application-hosted-media-bots

Did you follow all the steps to register the bot app? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot#bot-registration

You need to explicitly add permissions to access media, and later to grant by an administrator of the azure account.

If you did all that, could you please share what kind of exception/error are you getting?